# How can I change the name of the API stage in a SAM template?

Tags: aws-lambda, aws-api-gateway, aws-sam-cli

I'm using SAM to deploy a Lambda function and make it callable over HTTP with via API Gateway using roughly this template snipplet:

```
MyFunction:
  Type: AWS::Serverless::Function
  Properties:
    …
    Events:
      MyApi:
        Type: Api
        Properties:
          Path: /
          Method: any
```

This works, but it creates an API stage called "Prod", which has to be used as a prefix for all URLs. I don't want my URLs to be "https://something/Prod/foo", I want them to be "https://something/v1/foo", i.e. something that I choose.

How do I change the name of the stage?

I have tried declaring the API as a separate resource, and used the `StageName` property to set the name of the stage, however, that requires me to also set `DefinitionBody`, and that seems to be a deep rabbit hole.

```
MyFunction:
  Type: AWS::Serverless::Function
  Properties:
    …
    Events:
      MyApi:
        Type: Api
        Properties:
          Path: /
          Method: any
          RestApiId: !Ref MyApi

MyApi:
  Type: AWS::Serverless::Api
  Properties:
    StageName: v1
    DefinitionBody:
      ???
```

I know that `???` in the example above is supposed to be Swagger, but I would prefer to not have to write anything there, the template is getting verbose enough at is. Since I don't have to write this part if I can just live with the stage name "Prod" it seems to me that there must be a way to avoid having to write anything there and just set the stage name.

How can I change the name of the stage without having to write a lot of template code and/or Swagger?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

SAM Version 1.7.0 removed the need to specify a DefinitionBody or DefinitionUri so you should now be able to do exactly what you mention on your second example without having to include a DefinitionBody:

```
MyFunction:
  Type: AWS::Serverless::Function
  Properties:
    …
    Events:
      MyApi:
        Type: Api
        Properties:
          Path: /
          Method: any
          RestApiId: !Ref MyApi

MyApi:
  Type: AWS::Serverless::Api
  Properties:
    StageName: v1
```